# Awk:- how to process text of elb-describe-lbs to know only avilability zone

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, awk

A typical long view output of elb-descibe-lbs is like:-

```
 Prompt:- elb-describe-lbs --region xxxxx  --headers  --lbs xxxxxx  --show-    long view
    LOAD_BALANCER,NAME,DNS_NAME,CANONICAL_HOSTED_ZONE_NAME,CANONICAL_HOSTED_ZONE_NAME_ID,HEALTH_CH    ECK,AVAILABILITY_ZONES,SUBNETS,VPC_ID,INSTANCE_ID,LISTENER_DESCRIPTIONS,BACKEND_SERVER_DESCRIP    TIONS,SOURCE_SECURITY_GROUP,SECURITY_GROUPS,CREATED_TIME,SCHEME
LOAD_BALANCER,xxxxxx,xxxxx.xxxxxx.elb.amazonaws.com,xxx-    xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.elb.amazonaws.com,xxxxxxx," {interval=xx,target=HTTP:xx/index.html,timeout=5,healthy-threshold=xx,unhealthy-threshold=xx}","eu-west-1b, eu-west-1a",(nil),(nil),"xxxxxx","
```

I would like to only get the Availability zones information so I am using awk as:-

```
elb-describe-lbs --region xxxxx  --headers  --lbs xxxxx  --show-long view |  awk -F,  'NR {print $7}'
```

it gives output as:-

```
AVAILABILITY_ZONES
target=HTTP:xx/index.html
```

However I would like to get Availability zones information below its header but because of the delimiter as "comma" it is coming on feild $11 of awk.

for example:-

```
elb-describe-lbs --region eu-west-1  --headers  --lbs scc-emeaprod-tw  --show-long view |  awk -F,  'NR {print $7,$11,$12}'
```

output is

```
AVAILABILITY_ZONES LISTENER_DESCRIPTIONS BACKEND_SERVER_DESCRIPTIONS
target=HTTP:xx/index.html "eu-west-1b  eu-west-1a"
```

how can I manipulate text here for column 1 and column 2 so that I get availability zone below  its header

.

Comment: You can remove the `NR` since its always true, its not needed.

Comment: as you know the order you're expecting the header in, why not just print it as string before you print `$7`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would migrate away the old CLI and try the new AWS CLI (http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

`aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-names awseb-e-i-AWSEBLoa-12*****0U --region us-east-1 --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[].AvailabilityZones[]" --output text`

Comment: Sebsto,  i  am also trying here to get cross-zone-load balancer attribute via following command:-                                    aws elb describe-load-balancer-attributes --load-balancer-name 'xxxxx' --region us-east-1 --query "LoadBalancerAttributes[].CrossZoneLoadBalancing[]" --output text           however it is giving me error                                       "expected a character buffer object"  can you help ?

Comment: Are you running latest version of AWS CLI ?  This package updates very frequently.  Try "sudo yum upgrade awscli" or "pip install awscli --upgrade"

Comment: Yeah its latest.  xxxxxxxx aws --version
aws-cli/1.3.6 Python/2.7.2 Darwin/12.5.0

Comment: weird - I just tested it again on my laptop and it works : $ aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-names awseb-e-i-AWSEBLoa-12*****S0U --region us-east-1 --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[].AvailabilityZones[]" --output text
us-east-1c us-east-1b us-east-1d

Comment: $ aws --version
aws-cli/1.3.6 Python/2.7.5 Darwin/13.1.0

Comment: the only differences I see with you : I have a more recent version of Python and Mac OS X (10.9.2)